# determining the line terminator in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, text-files, eol

I'm writing a config file and I need to define if the process expects a windows format file or a unix format file. I've got a copy of the expected file - is there a way I can check if it uses \n or \r\n without exiting emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it says (DOS) on the modeline when you open the file on Unix, the line endings are Windows-style. If it says (Unix) when you open the file on Windows, the line endings are Unix-style.

From the Emacs 22.2 manual (Node: Mode Line):

> If the buffer's file uses
>   carriage-return linefeed, the colon
>   changes to either a backslash ('\') or
>   '(DOS)', depending on the operating
>   system.  If the file uses just
>   carriage-return, the colon indicator
>   changes to either a forward slash
>   ('/') or '(Mac)'.  On some systems,
>   Emacs displays '(Unix)' instead of the
>   colon for files that use newline as
>   the line separator.

Here's a function that – I think – shows how to check from elisp what Emacs has determined to be the type of line endings. If it looks inordinately complicated, perhaps it is.

```
(defun describe-eol ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((eol-type (coding-system-eol-type buffer-file-coding-system)))
    (when (vectorp eol-type)
      (setq eol-type (coding-system-eol-type (aref eol-type 0))))
    (message "Line endings are of type: %s"
             (case eol-type
               (0 "Unix") (1 "DOS") (2 "Mac") (t "Unknown")))))
```

Comment: This assumes you're not running on Windows.  There, the modeline would be \ for \r\n or (Unix) for \n.

Comment: Surely the OP wants a programmatic solution and not a visual inspection of the modeline?

Comment: Nope! wanted a visual one, although the elsip is nice to have.

Comment: In modern versions of Emacs, replace `case` with `cl-case` and load `cl-lib`.

Answer (score 2):

If you go in hexl-mode (M-x hexl-mode), you shoul see the line termination bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in emacs using find-file-literally.  If lines have ^M symbols at the end, it expects a windows format text file.

Answer (score 0):

The following Elisp function will return `nil` if no `"\r\n"` terminators appear in a file (otherwise it returns the point of the first occurrence). You can put it in your `.emacs` and call it with `M-x check-eol`.

```
(defun check-eol (FILE)
  (interactive "fFile: ")
  (set-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*check-eol*"))
  (insert-file-contents-literally FILE)
  (let ((point (search-forward "\r\n")))
    (kill-buffer nil)
    point))
```

Comment: But modern versions of Emacs convert CRLF to LF when loading (and back when saving), so you won't have any \r characters in your buffer.  You need to check the buffer's coding system.

Comment: Yes, it will, but you didn't mention using find-file-literally first.